# File.WriteAllLines encoding

Tags: c#, encoding, html-to-pdf, system.io.file

I make an html to pdf converter, but when I write my text into the file with the  File.WriteAllLines(), I get weird Symbols.

This is the code I use at the moment:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

Document doc = app.Documents.Open(FileName: @"C:\Users\krisb\Documents\NewHeapTemplate.docx", ReadOnly: false);
app.Selection.Find.Execute("<Index>");
app.Selection.TypeText("<h1>New Heap</h1>");

doc.SaveAs2(@"C:\Users\krisb\Documents\voorbeeld2.html", FileFormat: WdSaveFormat.wdFormatWebArchive);
doc.Close();

string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\krisb\Documents\voorbeeld2.html");

for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
{
    if (lines[i].Contains("&lt;"))
    {
        lines[i] = lines[i].Replace("&lt;", "<");
    }
    if (lines[i].Contains("&gt;"))
    {
        lines[i] = lines[i].Replace("&gt;", ">");
        Console.WriteLine(lines[i]);
    }
}

File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\krisb\Documents\voorbeeld2.html", lines, Encoding.UTF8);

Document doc2 = app.Documents.Open(FileName: @"C:\Users\krisb\Documents\voorbeeld2.html", ReadOnly: false);
doc2.SaveAs2(@"C:\Users\krisb\Documents\kristemplate.pdf", FileFormat: WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF);
doc2.Close();
app.Quit();
```

And in my pdf I get all those weird symbols:

```
ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½
```

I know this problem by writing and by the encoding, but I have no idea how I can fix this.
Does someone know a solution?

Comment: "[The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)"

Comment: Where are you using `File.WriteAllLines()` to write to the PDF file? Your code doesn't match your description.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Sorry i mean my html File

Comment: So if you look at the HTML file, it has the wrong characters in it, is that what you're saying?

Comment: @MatthewWatson Yes

Comment: I suspect you should be using `WdSaveFormat.wdFormatHTML`, not `WdSaveFormat.wdFormatWebArchive`

Comment: @MatthewWatson Yes that was the issue, and i used the wrong encode

Comment: @UweKeim: awesome link. Thanks.

Comment: How do you see "all those weird symbols"? Are you opening the PDF file in notepad or in a PDF viewer?

Comment: @HansKesting in a pdf viewer